# Why is the CiviCRM Data Processor "Country" field displayed as a number in Word Press Content Views?

Tags: wordpress

I successfully installed Content Views CiviCRM with CiviCRM Data Processor for pulling data via Content Views in WordPress. This integration that is explained [here](https://github.com/agileware/content-views-civicrm-data-processor) works fine. However, I'm encountering a problem that I don't know if it's a bug or a mishandling on my part: The country field is displayed as a number (e.g. I get 1193 instead of Slovenia). How can I fix this? Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 2):

The country name should display correctly if you set the field from 'Raw field value' to 'Option label'.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much Rebecca!